# ArcMap Field Calculator Python string concatenation malfunction

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, arcgis-10.4, python-parser

I am trying to concatenate three fields into one using Python with the rjust padding function.

My function in the code box is the following:

```
def AutoSchluessel(gmk, zae, nen):
       return "{}0{}{}".format(gmk, str(zae).rjust(7,"0"), str(nen).rjust(5,"0"))
```

And the Expression is:

```
flcode = AutoSchluessel( !gmkgcode!, !zaehler!, !nenner!)
```

What i am getting is for the fields is the following result:

> gmkgcode = 5902;
>   zaehler = 32;
>   nenner = 17
>
> flcode = 5902.0000032.0017.0

It should in my opinion though result in something without points (59020000003200017).
What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to force the number to not having any decimal digits. Adding `int()` will solve the problem I think. If the field that holds the original numbers has type of `double`, it is better to round the number to whole number before add `int()` function to them.

Here is a code that worked for me, but I tested it on two fields not three fields, as in your case, but you can add another field in the same way:

```
def AutoSchluessel(x,y):
    return "{0}{1}".format(str(int(round(x,0))).rjust(10,"0"), str(int(round(y,0))).rjust(12,"0"))
```

I have 2 Fields `X = 246715.91` and `Y = 4172742.24`

After running the above code, I got `0000246716000004172742` (The desired output)

Without `int()`, I got the same results as yours `00246716.00004172742.0`, which is incorrect

Comment: Thanks! Yes, my bad, the input fields indeed were "Double" which I didn't even check because it makes no sense as there will only be integers in them.
@PolyGeo: I marked this as the accepted answear as the code improvements are shown here as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your Python code seems valid because when I run:

```
def AutoSchluessel(gmk, zae, nen):
       return "{}0{}{}".format(gmk, str(zae).rjust(7,"0"), str(nen).rjust(5,"0"))

gmk = 5902
zae = 32
nen = 17

flcode = AutoSchluessel(gmk, zae, nen)

print flcode
```

it prints out `59020000003200017`

If your three input fields are integer then I would expect the same result within the field calculator.

However, if one of those fields is a float or double then I could imagine the points being introduced.